# Rails How to get Posts ordered by number of Comments - not to return Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get the posts sorted by the number of comments? (most comments first)

posts has_many comments
comments belong_to posts

Comment: Post some of your code, posts controller etc

Comment: @post = Post.all is all i have now.

Comment: I'm using UUIDs? does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@posts = Post.includes(:comments).order("comments.size ASC")

Comment: this returns #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post:0x88d60d34>   - how am I supposed to parse that? or make it into an array?

Comment: In Post model... Please add method


def comments_count
  comments.count
end

In controller you can do...

Post.all.sort_by(&:comments_count)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is Rails counter_cache feature. It's a separate column in your posts table in database, where comments quantity is stored. it updates automatically every time you create new or delete a comment.

First, you need to add a column in posts table. Here is migration:

add_column :microposts, :comments_count, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false

After that change the code in your comment model to something like that:

belongs_to :micropost, :counter_cache => true

After all these changes your comments_count column in post will increment every time you create new comment and decrement every time you delete a comment. Also, you can sort posts by this column's value as well like this:

@posts = Post.order('comments_count ASC').all